# Avoid custom field value to be cleared on update cart totals ajax event in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm experiencing an issue with the output of a custom field within the WooCommerce cart-totals.php template.

I've added custom `<tr>` markup to the `<table>` tag found inside cart-totals.php, which is the element that shows your subtotal, taxes, fields to calculate shipping.

My function simply checks for a range of values stored in a custom field and echos text, the issue I'm having is that when I change my shipping option, say from air shipping to ground, the cart updates through ajax and changes my custom field value to empty. This doesn't happen when updating cart quantities, updating totals or on page load, just when changing shipping option.

Any advice to fix this would be much appreciated!

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">

  <tr class="cart-tier-discount">

    <th>Rewards Discount</th>

    <td>

      <?php
        $progress = get_the_author_meta( 'tier_progress_value', $user->ID );

        if ( $progress > 0.01 && $progress < 150 ) {
          echo '0%';
        }
        if ( $progress >= 150 && $progress < 300 ) {
          echo '10%';
        }
        if ( $progress >= 300 && $progress < 500 ) {
          echo '15%';
        }
        if ( $progress >= 500 ) {
          echo '20%';

        } 
      ?>

    </td>

  </tr> 

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead *(without editing `cart_totals.php` template)*. So you will need before to remove temporarily your changes from `cart_totals.php` template file.

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'cart_totals_rewards_before_shipping'  );
function cart_totals_rewards_before_shipping() {
    // Only for logged in users
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    $progress = (int) get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'tier_progress_value', true );

    if ( $progress >= 0 && $progress < 150 )
        $percentage = '0%';
    elseif ( $progress >= 150 && $progress < 300 )
        $percentage = '10%';
    elseif ( $progress >= 300 && $progress < 500 )
        $percentage = '15%';
    else
        $percentage = '20%';

    echo  '<tr class="cart-tier-discount">
    <th>' . __("Rewards Discount", "") . '</th>
    <td>' . $percentage .'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> Then when changing the shipping method on cart totals update event, the value is still there:
>
> [image]

Comment: Works perfectly of course! Very interesting that adding the markup through add_action instead of directly in the template prevents the issue.